Can i use one Package name into two Android Project with no anyType of issue or problem
I want to use one Package name in my two different Android Project. How can I?
I just tried but i got error and I cannot install that two project apps in my mobile as same time i have to uniStall one to install another one but i want to two apps as installed in my mobile with no changing package name and no any issue or problem....

You can use the same package name in multiple Android projects but then only one of those apps can be installed at a time on a device.
This is defined by the Android OS and can not be changed. Every installed app has to have a unique package name.
